# Moment(enero 1, 2017) gives Invalid Date. How to make moment() understand spanish format?

Tags: momentjs

The below code gives Invalid Date

```
moment.locale('es');
var dt = moment('enero 1, 2017');
alert(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to tell moment the format of the date you are trying to parse. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ for details.

In your case, the second line should be `var dt = moment('enero 1, 2017', 'MMMM DD, YYYY')` (note the second string parameter to tell moment how to try and parse the date you provided)